# What would be an interesting example of a Co-algebra with a base category other than Set?

Tags: category-theory, coalgebras

In most or perhaps all the examples of a co-algebra that I have seen, the properties of sets as the base category was used, like the existence of products and co-product and Cartesian closeness. Does anyone have an example of a co-algebra and a system which makes use of more peculiar categorical properties?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you just asking for an example of a coalgebra internal to a category other than $\text{Set}$ or are you asking for an example of a coalgebra internal to a category which is not concretizable? Examples of the first kind are easy to find (e.g. coalgebras in $(\text{Vect}, \otimes)$).

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan Thanks. That was actually enlightening comment.

Comment: (Examples of the second kind can be found in the pointed homotopy category of topological spaces, which is known not to be concretizable. For example, $S^1$ is a comonoid in this category.)

Comment: You can also learn about corings which are coalgebras in the category of $(A,A)$-bimodules where $A$ is some unital associative algebra over a commutative ring $k$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76509/what-is-a-coalgebra-intuitively) and [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130643/is-it-true-that-nature-promotes-products/130645#130645) for several examples of coalgebras in categories other than $(\text{Set}, \times)$.